# Unity game crashes on IOS but works perfect on Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, crash

I have made an app that takes pictures of the screen and saves it in Gallery with name i have given using DateTime class and my own prefix. The code on Android works perfect, when you press the button it takes the screenshot and it finishes everything. But the story is not the same on iOS. It crashes whenever the button is pressed. This is the code :

```
Flash.SetActive(true); 

RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight,   24);          
cam.targetTexture = rt;  

Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);  

cam.Render();  

RenderTexture.active = rt;  
screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);  
cam.targetTexture = null;  
RenderTexture.active = null;  
Destroy(rt); 

byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();

filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);  
FullSharePath = "/storage/emulated/0/GarderobaShots/" + filename + ".png";  

Texture2D textu = new Texture2D(900,1320, TextureFormat.RGBAFloat, false);  
textu.LoadImage(bytes);  
textu.Apply();  

spr = Sprite.Create(textu ,new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, textu.width, textu.height), new Vector2(1f, 1f), 100.0f);  
ShareAbleObject.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = spr;  

ShareAbleObject.SetActive(true);  
NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(textu, "AmazingGirlsShots", filename + ".png");  
takeHiResShot = false;
```

Just a quick introduction to code It switches MainCamera of the scene with some camera i have(it's smaller and it has different canvas(only text)) then it activates object i have called Flash which is white flash on screen,it goes off by itself Afterwards it render texture from screen and saves it in

`Texture2D textu`

Full Share path is the path where this file will be stored so the user wants, he can share it or see it from game

`NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(textu, "AmazingGirlsShots", filename".png");`

It's plugin I took for ios and android that refreshes gallery for an image to be shown in the gallery, otherwise its just somewhere in phone I think that cant be the problem as its check plugin that many people use.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the **Permission Privacy Settings** in **Info.plist**.

[image]